# How to import browser Module in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, browser

How to get module import in Angular typescript?
I want to get the id of the latest download in the browser.

```
browser.downloads.onChanged.addListener((downloadDelta) => {
    if (downloadDelta.state && downloadDelta.state.current === 'complete') {
        const downloadId = downloadDelta.id;
        console.log(`Download ID: ${downloadId}`);
    }
});
```

I am getting an error on `browser`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are encountering is because the 'browser' object is not recognized in Angular's TypeScript environment. The 'browser' object is typically available in the context of browser extensions, such as those developed using the WebExtensions API.

If you are working on a regular Angular project without browser extension capabilities, you won't have access to the 'browser' object or its related functionality. The 'browser' object is specific to the browser extension environment.

If you want to interact with browser downloads in a regular Angular project, you will need to use alternative methods. One common approach is to utilize the HTML5 File API or Angular's HttpClient module to handle file downloads.

Here's an example of using the HttpClient module in Angular to trigger a file download and obtain the download ID:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-download',
  template: `
    <button (click)="downloadFile()">Download File</button>
  `
})
export class DownloadComponent {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  downloadFile() {
    const fileUrl = 'https://example.com/file.pdf';
    this.http.get(fileUrl, { responseType: 'blob' })
      .subscribe((response: Blob) => {
        // Handle the downloaded file
        const downloadId = /* Obtain the download ID */;
        console.log(`Download ID: ${downloadId}`);
      });
  }
}
```

In this example, the `HttpClient` module is used to make an HTTP request to the file URL, and the `responseType` is set to `'blob'` to receive the file as a binary blob. Once the file is downloaded, you can process it as needed and retrieve any necessary information.

Please note that this approach assumes you are downloading files from a remote server. If you are looking to handle downloads triggered by a user action, such as clicking a link, you can use the HTML5 `download` attribute or similar techniques to initiate the download.